# How to "keep" Lexplore/Rexplore/Explore position?

Tags: buffers, multiple-files, jumplist, location-list

When navigating large projects, in IDEs like intellij, I keep opening and closing the navigation/file tree tab and moving around files.

On vim I tried to create a similar functionality, adding to my `~/.vimrc`: `nnoremap <F2> :Lexplore<CR>` which allows me to open and close a file list on the left window.

It works fine but every time i close it, i'm back at the project root (or more correctly, the working directory i ran vim)

`:Explore` instead opens always in the path of the active buffer.

**Is there a way to open exactly where it was (both directory location, and selected line) as it was before it was closed?**

I already tried to mark the file list as a buffer `set bl`. Did nothing. doesn't even show up when i list buffers. Think i might be misunderstanding how this functions.

setting `g:netrw_chgwin=2` as the documentation for Explorer suggest. Changes nothing related to my issue.

Comment: Welcome to vi SE. I don't quite get what you expect to happen but I suspect you might be interested in reading `:help netrw-:Sexplore`, `:help CTRL-O` and maybe also `:help :pwd`.

Comment: There’s also :Rexplore and http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/

Comment: @Friedrich thanks for the welcome and comment. What you suggested is my 4th paragraph on the question. I just want something the "remembers" where it was as i toggle the window into view and out.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks. i considered nerdtree. but vim already have a dozen file explorer and nerdtree brings too many external binaries for things i have no use... (last missing piece for me is a way to remember the filetree position, and i'm not even sure nerdtree does that besides the many things i don't really need :)

Comment: My suggestion is actually pretty anti-nerdtree :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble my bad. it ends on a note to use nerdtree. But yeah, i'm doing pretty much what the article describe. My issue is that by using `:LExplorer` or `:RExplorer` or really any of those, they are all stateless. i want them to keep state somehow :)

Comment: No worries. Again, the link actually recommends against nerdtree (philosophically) or to use nerdtree with some specific settings to make it more netrw-like.